# How to check if a given URL string ends with "/index.*" or simply "/" and remove it, in PHP?

Tags: php, canonical-link

I'm trying to check for /index.[ php | htm | html | asp ], etc. (basically any wildcard suffix)

or simply "/"

to convert a canonical URL such as `http://www.example.com/index.php` or `http://www.example.com/` to just `http://www.example.com` so I can just use one consistent PHP variable in my `canonical`meta tag throughout all the pages on my site.

I dont want the script to effect URLs that are NOT homepages such as `http://www.example.com/page.php`

REGEX preferred, but not necessary.

I'm working from the variable `$current_Webpage_Complete_URL_Address` in "domain_info.php" from this script: http://www.perfecterrordocs.com

I want to use just one PHP variable, formed from modifying `$current_Webpage_Complete_URL_Address`, if that makes any sense.

Please ask for further clarification, if neccassary.

**Edit:** Also, I want the newly formed variable to be named 
`$current_Webpage_Canonical_URL_Address`

**Edit(2):** I just ran into another problem. Even when I do find a match with `preg_match` how do I remove that particular ending sub-string?

Comment: Have you tried to put together a regex for this already?

Comment: working on it now...

Comment: You might want to consider a shorter more concise variable naming convention. Or pretty soon there wont be enough editor to see a simple line of code

Answer (score 1):

Final Answer (Works Perfectly!!):

```
$current_Webpage_Canonical_URL_Address = preg_replace('/((\\index)\.[a-z]+)$/', '', $current_Webpage_Complete_URL_Address);

$current_Webpage_Canonical_URL_Address = preg_replace('/\/$/', '', $current_Webpage_Canonical_URL_Address);
```